# What is the biblical definition of a year?

Tags: definition

Nisan was defined just before the first Passover as the beginning of the year, but Rosh Hashanah is also celebrated as the first month. Is the latter merely traditional or it's also ordained. In either case is the preceding month then the last month of the year, ie a biblical year is 7 earthly or moonly months.

Comment: The biblical narrative shows [both Egyptian as well as Babylonian influence](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/revisions/39426/2), be it calendric, mythological, or otherwise.

Comment: meaning? it's not defined biblically? but externally influenced traditions?

Comment: The Hebrew calendar is Luni-solar calendar as described in great detail here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar  The months alternated between 29 and 30 days long because the lunar month is 29.5 days long.

Answer (score 1):

Biblical months were 30 days each, so a biblical year was 360 days.  This can be seen in the prophetic usages made of it in which each day of the prophecy would represent a year in literal time.

For example, 42 months in Revelation 11:2 and 13:5 was equivalent to "a time, and times, and half a time," (Rev. 12:14) and the "time" was a reference to a year.  So a time (one year) plus times (two years) plus half a time (half a year) was three and a half years.  Revelation 11:3 and 12:6 describe this as 1260 days, which help us know exactly how many days were in each month (1260/42 = 30).

Here are some of those texts:

> But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it
> not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they
> tread under foot **forty and two months**. (Revelation 11:2)
>
> And I will give power unto my two witnesses, and they shall prophesy
> **a thousand two hundred and threescore days**, clothed in sackcloth. (Revelation 11:3)
>
> And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and
> blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue **forty and two
> months**. (Revelation 13:5)
>
> And to the woman were given two wings of a great eagle, that she might
> fly into the wilderness, into her place, where she is nourished for
> **a time, and times, and half a time,** from the face of the serpent. (Revelation 12:14)
>
> And I heard the man clothed in linen, which was upon the waters of the
> river, when he held up his right hand and his left hand unto heaven,
> and sware by him that liveth for ever that it shall be for **a time,
> times, and an half;** and when he shall have accomplished to scatter
> the power of the holy people, all these things shall be finished.
> (Daniel 12:7)

Comment: "Biblical months were 30 days each, so a biblical year was 360 days. This can be seen in the prophetic usages made of it in which each day of the prophecy would represent a year in literal time." I've heard this idea of a "360 day prophetic year" a lot, but never actually seen any supporting evidence for it. Even if the months were all 30 days, didn't they make up for it with an intercalary month?

Comment: @curiousdannii Revelation 11:2 and 3 describe the same time period in terms of months and in days.  It's simple math from there to understand how many days were in a month.

Comment: Is it applicable outside Revelation though? I've seen people apply the 360 "year" to anytime the Bible mentions years...

Comment: @curiousdannii The Bible is consistent in its usage.  Time is important to God, prophetically and otherwise.

Comment: @curiousdannii: See my comment on the main post.